# Using multiple constructors with ArrayList don't work

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I was using multiple constructor from the same class, but a few days ago I got a 'rare' problem. The constructor initializes all the fields =(

I have Ejercicio.java class

```
   public class Ejercicios {
    int Id_Ejercicio;
    String Descripcion;
    String Finalidad;
    String Duracion;

    //Constructor
    public Ejercicios() {
        super();
    }

    //Constructor with 2 fields 
    public Ejercicios(int id_Ejercicio, String descripcion) {
        super();
        Id_Ejercicio = id_Ejercicio;
        Descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    //Constructor with 4 fields 
    public Ejercicios(int id_Ejercicio, String descripcion, String finalidad, String duracion) {
        super();
        Id_Ejercicio = id_Ejercicio;
        Descripcion = descripcion;
        Finalidad = finalidad;
        Duracion = duracion;
    }
}
```

And the Lista_Ejercicios.java class

```
public class List_Ejercicios {

    ArrayList<Ejercicios> lejer;

    public List_Ejercicios() {
        super();
    }
}
```

And my principal class where I try to use these differents constructors

```
public Response Principal(SQLQuery){
   List<Ejercicios> listaEJER = new ArrayList<Ejercicios>();
   dbCon = new ConexionBD();
   ResultSet rslt;

    try {
        conn = (Connection) ConexionBD.setDBConnection();
        rslt = dbCon.getResultSet(SQLQuery, conn);  
        while(rslt.next()){             
            listaEJER.add(new Ejercicios( rslt.getInt(1),rslt.getString(2) ));
        }       
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  //finally block code
   return Response.ok(listaEJER.toArray()).build();
}
```

I was using 'Advanced Rest Client' for Chrome and I don't have an idea why I receive the 4 fields instead 2 like I especified in the constructor

```
...
{
descripcion: "Jump as high as you can"
id_Ejercicio: 1
finalidad: null
duracion: null
}
...
```

I have in trouble, these constructors work two weeks ago I don't have any clue why currently its running doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They did **not** work two weeks ago. You've changed something. When you declare a field in your class, that field is *always* there. If you don't initialise it in your constructor, it will be auto-initialised. For classes, this default value is `null`, whereas for primitives it is `0`, `false` etc. However, this behaves exactly the same as if you had initialised it to that value in the constructor - `myEjercicios.Finalidad` (use naming conventions please) will be `null`, as it is an auto-initialised object of type `String`.

As for fixing this issue, it shouldn't be hard to write some code to not print values that are `null`. If you want a different set of fields, however, you **must** declare two different classes (perhaps one extending the other).

Comment: I was checking the repository of the proyect, and you have reason. It was modified adding a new field, so I am in trouble with these 'news' fields with null value. Sorry !